# Instaling Zend: Can browse directories from browser but can't view pages

Tags: php, zend-framework

I created a zend app in my htdocs directory:

```
zf create project taskManager
```

[I then followed all the instructions on the Zend framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html) setup page; when I go to `localhost:8888` all I get are the directories for my project, but the homepage will not load. I tried restarting MAMP but still no luck. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find your Zend directory which will be in the /library directory of wherever you originally downloaded the framework, then move the Zend directory into the /library directory of your new app. Go to `http://localhost:8888/taskManager/public/` and you should see the welcome page.

Comment: Wow, that was really informative! I can't believe this extremely imperative step isn't in the poorly written Zend docs. Thanks a lot Chopper Draw Lion4!